# Mobile safari crash with ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ajax, wordpress

Hello I have site where I'm loading sliders with ajax it works very well on desktop and android but on IOS Iphone after load 2nd row of sliders Safari crashes. Do I have any errors in my code? What can cause my error?

I'm using wordpress custom query for it and displays 1 slider for 2 custom types on page. Here is my html [markup](http://pastebin.com/xQP7RnvP)
I want add that sliders have big pictures.

```
    currentPage = 2;
containerItemSelector = ".home-row";
postItemSelector = ".left-col";
containerItemSelector2 = ".home-row";
postItemSelector2 = ".right-col";
counter = 1;
allow = true;
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if(allow && $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > $(document).height()-100) {
    allow = false;
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>?paged=" + currentPage,
      data: "",
      success: function(results) {
        var item = $(containerItemSelector + " > " + postItemSelector, results);
        item.each(function(i) {
          $(containerItemSelector).append($(this));
          $(this).find('.description').fadeIn(500);
          var slider = $(this).find('.slider-left').attr('id');
          jssor_slider_left.push(new $JssorSlider$(slider, options1));
          var total = jssor_slider_left.length - 1;
          var parentWidth = jssor_slider_left[total].$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;

            if (parentWidth)
                jssor_slider_left[total].$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth,954));
            else
                window.setTimeout(scales, 30);
            $(this).find('.img-wrap2').fadeOut(1500, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            if(counter % 2 == 0){
                $(this).closest('.right-col').after("<div class='clearfix'> </div>");

        }
        counter++;
        });
            var item1 = $(containerItemSelector2 + " > " + postItemSelector2, results);
        item1.each(function(i) {
          $(containerItemSelector2).append($(this));
          $(this).find('.description').fadeIn(500);
          var slider2 = $(this).find('.slider-right').attr('id');
          jssor_slider_right.push(new $JssorSlider$(slider2, options1));
          var total1 = jssor_slider_right.length - 1;
          var parentWidth1 = jssor_slider_right[total1].$Elmt.parentNode.clientWidth;
            if (parentWidth1)
                jssor_slider_right[total1].$ScaleWidth(Math.min(parentWidth1,954));
            else
                window.setTimeout(scales, 30);

            $(this).find('.img-wrap2').fadeOut(1500, function(){
                $(this).remove();
            });
            if(counter % 2 == 0){
                $(this).closest('.right-col').after("<div class='clearfix'> </div>");

        }
        counter++;


        });

       currentPage++;
       allow = true;
      },
      error: function(results) {
        if(results.status == 404) {
          $(".xhrStatus").html('No more posts to show...');
        }
        else {
          $(".xhrStatus").html('Error retrieving posts...');
        }
      }

    });
  }
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Can you narrow down where the crash occurs?

Comment: Yea, like I said at first page loads and I got row of 2 sliders, then when I scroll down and load second page of sliders then crash appears.

Comment: I meant where in the code.

Comment: I quess the problem is in ajax call. But I don't know it for sure.